# messed up with soap api

Tags: web-services, api, rest, soap

Hey guys am developing an api for my website ..i have came to know about soap api..i know api can be created using rest..but the things which came to be confused for me when soap protocol came into action..i have reffered many soap tutorials over the internet and i became really confused.

Is soap used for making apis or linking different apis together ??...Is soap do the same function of Rest artchitecture..Can a website api be build through soap ??..

Hope you guys can help me in understanding soap...Any help would be really appreciated .Thanx in advance..

Comment: erm... no? Man, it's honestly really hard to work out what exactly you are asking here. REST and SOAP are both ways of formalising clients getting data from servers. REST is lot looser on how to implement it, relying very much on HTTP. SOAP is a more rigid framework that really is more transport transparent. Generally, you do not make an API for your website, you use it for web services, and you stick to some convention so other programmers don't try to kill you when they have to suffer what ever terrible API you come up with; and don't worry, it's not just you, all APIs are terrible :P

Comment: @thecoshman i didnt get you ..so is soap also used for making website apis ??.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 'website api', because to me it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general SOAP is distributed computing style and REST is web style (web is also a distributed computing model).
please read more [here](http://javapapers.com/web-service/rest-vs-soap/)

Comment: ..my question is can we design a web api with soap ?

Comment: Yes.the choice between Rest or SOAP is dependence on what kind of service you want to provide in the application whether it is Resource oriented or service oriented. hope that helps

Comment: YES THAnks it helped ..can we make aan api fOR dekstop app with soap ??

Comment: I don't think it advisable to use SOAP for desktop app. SOAP protocol runs on the top oF TCP protocol.

Comment: No it doesn't. SOAP is transport protocol agnostic. Even if it SOAP was tied to TCP, why would that make it unadvisable for a desktop program?

Comment: @monty024 thanx for the info..well is it posible to make api for dekstop app with rest ??

Comment: @monty024 is it possible to make a dekstop app api with rest ??

Comment: You can represent your desktop application resource to urls, Please read about REST concept then you can decide. I think for desktop application no Rest api is available  you need to write everything from  scratch.